# frequency domain to time domain with magnitude and phase

Tags: matlab, fourier

I have a signal magnitude and phase in frequency domain. I need to have it in time domain but I really have no idea how to do it. I heard something about mirroring the signal but I'm kinda new at this. I have tried to do something like this in matlab but I'm clearly missing the point. And how do I define the time vector?

```
z = A .* exp(i*phase);
X = ifft(z);
```

I've attached the signal plot

[image: plot]

Comment: if `z` is your frequency domain vector, then `X` is your time domain vector. Done! Where's the issue?

Comment: I am really new to fourier transform and I've read that it's not enough to simply do ifft, that I have to mirror of these phase and magnitude values - it's all really hazy for me and X doesn't produce the results I seek. Thank you for your response

Comment: but it really is the time domain if `z` is your frequency domain. There's really nothing ambiguous about that. It's kind  of hard to help you understand the things you've read "somewhere" and understand what you seek when all you tell us what you *don't* seek. Please explain why this isn't what you need, and what you've read.

Comment: Well I plot it and it's near nowhere the original signal so something is clearly wrong with what I've done here. Thank you for your response

Comment: ... How about you *add* the original signal, and your `X` so that we can actually try to understand what you want?

Comment: I'm really sorry, it's just overwhelming me, I didn't intend to make anyone angry

Comment: not angry. Just confused how you're expecting us to help you if you neither tell us *what* you've read, specifically, nor *what* you want!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I don't use MATLAB, but I think this Python example represents what you may be asking.

```
import numpy as np

A = 3 + 4j
k = 5
N = 128

Z = np.zeros(N, dtype='complex')
Z[k]   = A
Z[N-k] = np.conj( A )

z = np.fft.ifft(Z)

print( z )
```

This will generate a real valued pure tone (all the imaginary values are zero to the limit of precision) signal with 5 cycles in the frame.  The "mirroring" means that for a real signal the DFT is a conjugate mirror image, i.e. $Z[k] = Z^*[N-k]$.  It is common convention to use X, but I like Z too.

Comment: yeah, you have defined the mirroring part perfectly! thank you kindly